# How do you pass a sql query to another function in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I tried asking this before but didnt really get an answer so Ill try to rephrse it. I cant figure out how to pass the results of a multi line query to another function or page, especially using PDO. Would I execute the loop in the original function?

```
public function viewGallery(){
    $pQuery = 'SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE  userId = ?';
    $viewGallery = $this-> _db ->prepare($pQuery);
    $viewGallery ->bindParam(1, $id);
    $viewGallery ->execute();

    while ($get_row = $viewGallery ->fetch()){
        $id = $get_row['id'];
    }
}
```

then another page that accesses this:

```
 //echo the results of viewGallery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the results you want from viewGallery() then echo them on the other page.

You could return an array of results (ids by the looks of it) and then whiz through them with a while loop on your other page to display them

```
while ($get_row = $viewGallery ->fetch()){
    $id = $get_row['id'];
    $myBigArray[] = $id;
}

return $myBigArray;
```

Then on the other page just loop through and echo each result

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your SQL returns `col1`, `col2` and `col3`

You can do the following to pass the results:

```
while ($get_row = $viewGallery ->fetch())
{
    $col1 = $get_row['col1'];
    $col2 = $get_row['col2'];
    $col3 = $get_row['col3'];
    someFunctionNameThatEchoesResults($col1, $col2, $col3);
}
```

You could also put all the results into an array and *then* pass it to the other function:

```
$resArray=array();
while ($get_row = $viewGallery ->fetch())
{
    $col1 = $get_row['col1'];
    $col2 = $get_row['col2'];
    $col3 = $get_row['col3'];
    $resArray[]=array($col1, $col2, $col3);
}
someFunctionNameTheShowsResults($resArray);
```

Comment: Why not just `$resArray[] = $get_row`?

Comment: @Mahn Trying to make the answer as simple and configurable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply return the complete data set with `fetchAll()`

something like below

```
try {
    $dbh = PDO(/* Connection Info */);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM foo";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```